# Transparent axes.axhline in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to add a horizontal line to my axes to mark an important `y` value, so I'm using:

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = fig.add_axes((0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6))
ax.plot(...)
ax.axhline(100000, xmin=0, xmax=1, linewidth=0.3, color=(0, 0, 0, 0.75))
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)
canvas.print_figure("chart.pdf", dpi=300)
```

However I've got a few problems:

- What unit is the linewidth? points?
- The line doesn't seem to respect the alpha value in my colour. It's transparent when `a = 0` and opaque when `a > 0`, there's no semi-transparency. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using:

Mac OSX 10.6.7, Python 2.7, matplotlib 1.0.1, numpy 1.5.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Linewidth is in points.

The transparency works fine for me using matplotlib 1.0+.  Here is the code I used to test:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,10,.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axhline(.4, xmin=0, xmax=1, linewidth=0.3, color=(0, 0, 0, 0.75))
plt.show()
```

What is the plot you are trying to draw an `axhline` over?  Maybe there is a conflict with a particular type of plot.

Comment: That's very strange, for me I have to `ax.axhline(.4, xmin=0, xmax=10, linewidth=0.3, color=(0, 0, 0), alpha=0.75)`. I added some more code to give context in my question.

Comment: Ah.  So it is.  Fixed `xmax=1`.  So it seems you have found a bug.  I don't normally report bugs, so I can't advise.  If you post your version, OS, and code to reproduce the issue in your post, maybe it'll get some attention.